# Is there a simple way to test that an object has a set of properties and those properties are the right type/value?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm writing mocha tests to verify that a method is returning an object with a set of properties. I also need to verify that each property is the right type and in some cases the right range. Name property should exist and be a string. ID should be a number greater than 10000 etc.

Is there a way to quickly accomplish this without verifying it all manually?

I found something close but it checks that the value === something not it's type or range of valid values as far as I can see:

> .propertyVal(object, property, value, [message])
>
> @param{ Object }object @param{ String }property @param{ Mixed }value
>   @param{ String }message Asserts that object has a property named by
>   property with value given by value.
>
> assert.propertyVal({ tea: 'is good' }, 'tea', 'is good');

Comment: Some sort of deep equals (strict equals) with an expected response?

Comment: Have you considered using JsonSchema and a schema validator such as tv4 https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4